# Why using -1 in SQL

Tags: sql

So I was looking at a query made by a former employee and I noticed that he used -1 in the WHERE clause. I've tried searching online to find an explanation what the -1 does but I can't find an answer. Can anyone explain me what the function of this -1 is?

```
WHERE 
(
    @EmployeeId = -1 OR 
    tblReg.PurchaseOrderId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT r2.PurchaseOrderId 
                                FROM Registration r2 
                                INNER JOIN PurchaseOrder p2 ON p2.PurchaseOrderId = r2.PurchaseOrderId 
                                WHERE p2.statuscid = 1 AND r2.IsBillable = 1 AND r2.SetNonBillable = 0 AND r2.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
                                AND r2.RegistrationDate < @EndDate AND r2.RegistrationDate >= @StartDate)
)
```

Comment: If not selected, the parameter will likely be set to -1, in which case the second criteria will be used.

Comment: It's probably a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) meaning "no value". Some programming languages like older versions of .NET didn't support null numbers, so they used -1 to represent null. This is just a convention, though, it doesn't mean anything special. It's just a number.

Comment: It's just a number.  There must be cases where the parameter is set to -1.  Perhaps for "all employees" rather than one specific employee?

Comment: The expression `@EmployeeId = -1` is something specific to your system and not SQL in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of construct is probably used to mean "get all employees".  That is, when the variable `@EmployeeId` has the value `-1`, then all employees are returned.

The more typical way of handling this is with `NULL`:

```
where (@EmployeeId is null) or
      . . .
```

Your colleague's version assumes (probably safely) that the `id` is never negative.  However, it is always possible that someone will come along and invent some new meaning for the id.  A "fabulous idea" like "Let's give former employees a negative `EmployeeId` value" would break this -- and perhaps much other code.

Comment: Great! It indeed gives me back all employees. Was a bit confused already why he wouldn't just write `null`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EmployeeID may be only more or equal than 1. EmployeeID = -1 means that there is no employee matching this purchase.

It's not something from SQL. It's something that your Employee used to check something.